# Filter, Index, Match in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, match, transpose

I'm trying to understand what's going wrong but I'm terrible at this and trying to learn. I need the "Invoicing" sheet to create a list of dates students were present in the morning and afternoon as drop-ins for before/after care at school. So I need to match the name, then make a list of the column dates with a P in the cell below it. Easier to understand by looking at it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sd_rTMoKlngcwx8ORyzM7JyK_0Uy8CQYqrMo12eDLlQ/edit?usp=sharing

I've done something like this before with Filter, Index, and Match, but it was in a Transpose formula and I feel like I accidentally got it to work. Now I don't get why this isn't working.

I've looked through a lot of suggested questions already reviewed and either they're not quite what I need or I don't understand enough to adapt them to my own needs. What can I try next?

Comment: Spreadsheets involving formulae are on-topic here (as they are rather like programming). However, the details of the troublesome formulae need to be in the question itself. The reason for this is that if a question relies on an online sheet, the sheet will be repaired as soon as a valid answer is given, and the question will then no longer make sense for future readers. We want questions (and answers) here that people can learn from for years. Could you edit the question to show the formulae? (The link is fine, as long as the question does not wholly rely upon it). Thanks!

Comment: As a general tip for spreadsheet formulae, sometimes it helps to add additional columns, so that a complex formula can be broken down into pieces, rather than doing everything in one go. This helps with debugging where a formula is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try these in your `Invoicing` tab

***Cell M2***

```
=byrow(A2:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,ifna(join(", ",filter('Drop-In AM Attendance'!GD4:HE4,filter('Drop-In AM Attendance'!GD5:HE,'Drop-In AM Attendance'!A5:A=z)="P"))))))
```

***Cell N2***

```
=byrow(A2:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,ifna(join(", ",filter('Drop-In PM Attendance'!GD4:HE4,filter('Drop-In PM Attendance'!GD5:HE,'Drop-In PM Attendance'!A5:A=z)="P"))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and amazing. Thank you SO SO much! I have no idea what you even did but I'm going to watch videos bit by bit to try to figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using filter and match. I think offset is a little easier to use than index for this case.

```
=ifna(join(", ",FILTER('Drop-In AM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,offset('Drop-In AM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,match(A2,'Drop-In AM Attendance'!$A$5:A,0),0)="P")),"None")
```

Let's look first at just the offset

```
offset('Drop-In AM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,match(A2,'Drop-In AM Attendance'!$A$5:A,0),0)
```

This is saying to take the cells GD4:HE4 in the AM Attendance sheet and move down a certain number of rows. The number of rows is determined by which row matches cell A2. So the return of this will be the row of the AM attendance sheet for the student shown in A2.

Now, the Filter:

```
FILTER('Drop-In AM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,offset('Drop-In AM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,match(A2,'Drop-In AM Attendance'!$A$5:A,0),0)="P")
```

This is saying to take the dates in $GD$4:$HE$4, find the ones where the row we returned from the offset is equal to "P". By default, each date will return in a new cell. This is the reason for the JOIN() function.

The JOIN() takes all the dates that have the "P" for the student and separates them by ", "  (adding a comma and space between them and getting them down to one cell).

Lastly, the IFNA() function is saying if there is an #N/A error (which would happen if the student had no drop in dates) then it returns "None" instead of an error.

You can simply drag this formula down for all of the students, and then take the same thing with PM as so:

```
=ifna(join(", ",FILTER('Drop-In PM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,offset('Drop-In PM Attendance'!$GD$4:$HE$4,match(A2,'Drop-In PM Attendance'!$A$5:A,0),0)="P")),"None")
```

[image: Sample Output]